# MySQL (now() - Interval 1 Month) for this year only

Tags: mysql

I need some help with this.

I have the following SQL statement

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE MONTH(ORDERDATE) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

The problem is that it is returning data from last month but for all years...  Am I doing something wrong or is this a normal issue that people face with this function?

The problem I am facing is that if I use the YEAR(NOW()) the report I am writing will not show the data for 2016 when we hit 2017.  I'm trying to write a 6 month sales history report.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Added Information

```
SELECT * FROM DATA_WH.SALESORD_HDR WHERE MONTH(ORDERDATE) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

RETURNS....

'2015-08-14 00:00:00'

Comment: If you're writing a six month sales report, then shouldn't your `WHERE` clause be something like `WHERE ORDERDATE >= NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH` , rather than what you have in the question?

Comment: Yea, there is in the full SQL statement, but I am using this to keep it simple mate.  The problem with - INTERVAL 6 MONTH is that is goes and shows that months data only.... My issue is related to the YEAR also showing up.  So it will show this month - 6 which is March, but March 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016...

Comment: This isn't completely clear to me.  Please include some data which reveal what the problem is and why using `MONTH` is unsatisfactory.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisenIts very simple.  The NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH is returning dates from AUGUST in all years

Comment: Yes, but why can't you just use `YEAR` to restrict?

Comment: Because if I do that, then the report in Jan will not show the sales data from Dec 2016, Nov 2016, Oct 2016, Sept 2016...  That is exactly what I don't want to happen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `DATE_SUB` with `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM DATA_WH.SALESORD_HDR
WHERE ORDERDATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND
                        DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
```

This avoids the problem of having to deal with boundary conditions when using `MONTH` and `YEAR`.

**Edit:**

The above query will return records whose order date is between one and two months *old*.  If you want to identify orders from the previous calendar *month*, then you will have to do a bit more work.  Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM DATA_WH.SALESORD_HDR
WHERE ORDERDATE >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-', LPAD(MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 2, '0'), '-', YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))), '%d-%m-%Y') AND
      ORDERDATE <  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-', LPAD(MONTH(NOW()), 2, '0'), '-', YEAR(NOW())), '%d-%m-%Y')
```

The strategy here is to build the date boundaries (August 1 and September 1 of 2016, as of the time of writing this answer), using the `ORDERDATE`.

Here is a Fiddle showing this logic in action:

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Good suggestion mate, will give that a shot.  If it works I'll vote this up as the answer.

Comment: I've tried this Tim, it doesn't seem to be working.  It returned 0 rows, so there is no error with the statement.  What do you reckon?

Comment: What does your actual data look like?  _Should_ the query be returning anything?  Are there any records where the `ORDERDATE` is between 2 and 1 month old?

Comment: absolutely, I just ran an sql:  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DATA_WH.SALESORD_HDR WHERE MONTH(ORDERDATE) = '8' AND YEAR(ORDERDATE) = '2016'... It returned 1567 rows

Comment: Do you want records one month old, or records from the previous calendar month?  These are not the same thing.

Comment: From the previous calendar month... I think you are getting at something here Tim, I am probably going about this all wrong?  Is this the same as the other question?  Do I need to think about setting up some sort of calendar table to run reports against?

Comment: @upsideDownPaddy From what I can see, I don't see the need for a calendary table.  I updated my answer to give you a way to query orders which occurred in the previous calendar _month_.  You can easily extend this to other months if you need to.

Comment: You're a genius mate, worked perfectly.  Thanks a heap!  I owe you several beers!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add another condition with AND  with YEAR function

```
SELECT * FROM DATA_WH.SALESORD_HDR WHERE MONTH(ORDERDATE) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND YEAR(ORDERDATE)= YEAR(NOW());
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but you should read the chat between Tim and myself regarding why this isnt a good solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this kind of queries recently:
This query will get the first day of the month and the last day of the month , also if you can carefully check the query you should be able to see that I have add a function from mysql that check the last day if the month "last_day(now())"

```
SELECT *
FROM DATA_WH.SALESORD_HDR
WHERE ORDERDATE BETWEEN  date(concat(year(now()) , '-' ,month(now()) , '-01')) ,AND
                        date(concat(year(now()) , '-' ,month(now()) , '-' , day(last_day(now()))))
```

Comment: I just implement the response using last_dat function , i think is enough

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE MONTH(ORDERDATE) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and YEAR(ORDERDATE) = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

This should only return rows where the order date is in the previous month.